# Can not use apoc.uuid.install(), error caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to create unique ids for nodes for which I am trying to use apoc library.
But I am having problems when using the apoc.uuid.install()

Comment: What's are those problems??? Depict them to get help or visit the doc https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.uuid/apoc.uuid.install/

Comment: @Kanuor, you should include the full log trace for us to try and identify what is causing the error.

Comment: I get that error on neo4j sandbox.. but not on the local db instance in neo4j desktop